# Un-check Checkbox every 24 hours

Tags: flutter, dart

I am making a To-Do list application, and I'd like it on 24 hours to uncheck the tasks that have been checked.

Basically, alter the Checkbox widget's check.

How, do I approach that?

I have tried using Workmanager, initializing a periodic 24-hour background task when a task is checked.

But, if I use the callBackDispatcher method for the actions to take on 24 hours using workmanager plugin, I cannot really update the UI, or access Lists / methods, etc, because they are in my widget, and callBackDispatcher must be outside (used as a top-level function).

I've also tried to use the callbackDispatcher - declared as static, and NOT as a top-level function, but this way, the code does not execute at all, the callbackDispatcher function is not reached after the time passes.

workmanager package seems to be the way to go, but I cannot seem to make it work.

I store all my data in Firebase rtdb, also, I'd prefer not to use SharedPreferences.

I'd love it if any of you could give me a way to approach this.

[image]

Comment: you can use `DateTime` to compare the checkState.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on this approach? @MDYeasinSheikh

Answer (score 0):

You can follow a different approach `without relying on WorkManager`. Instead, you can use `Firebase's Realtime Database` and implement a mechanism to periodically update the task status.

**Note** : Initialize Firebase Realtime Database in your application. You can refer to Firebase documentation on how to set it up.

Refer : [Firebase Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start)

**Steps** :

1. Create a data model for your tasks that includes properties such as task name, completion status, and a timestamp for when the task was last checked.

```
class Task {
  String name;
  bool isCompleted;
  int lastCheckedTimestamp;

  Task({required this.name, this.isCompleted = false, required this.lastCheckedTimestamp});

  // Convert the object to a map for database storage
  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      'name': name,
      'isCompleted': isCompleted,
      'lastCheckedTimestamp': lastCheckedTimestamp,
    };
  }

  // Create a Task object from a map retrieved from the database
  factory Task.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return Task(
      name: map['name'],
      isCompleted: map['isCompleted'],
      lastCheckedTimestamp: map['lastCheckedTimestamp'],
    );
  }
}
```

2. Whenever a task is checked or unchecked, update the corresponding task in the Firebase Realtime Database.

```
void updateTaskCompletionStatus(Task task) {
  task.isCompleted = !task.isCompleted;
  task.lastCheckedTimestamp = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch;
  
  // Update the task in the Firebase Realtime Database
  FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child('tasks').child(taskId).update(task.toMap());
}
```

3. Set up a periodic timer using the `Timer.periodic` function. This timer will run a callback every `24 hours to update the task status`.

```
void startPeriodicTaskStatusUpdate() {
  Timer.periodic(const Duration(hours: 24), (_) {
    // Query the Firebase Realtime Database to retrieve all tasks
    FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child('tasks').once().then((DataSnapshot snapshot) {
      final tasks = Map<String, Task>.from(snapshot.value ?? {});
      
      // Iterate over each task and update the completion status if necessary
      tasks.forEach((taskId, taskData) {
        final task = Task.fromMap(taskData);
        
        // If the task was checked more than 24 hours ago and is completed, uncheck it
        final currentTime = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch;
        if (task.isCompleted && (currentTime - task.lastCheckedTimestamp) > 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000) {
          task.isCompleted = false;
          
          // Update the task in the Firebase Realtime Database
          FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child('tasks').child(taskId).update(task.toMap());
        }
      });
    });
  });
}
```

4. Call the `startPeriodicTaskStatusUpdate` function when your application starts or when the user logs in.

Comment: Does this solution solve your problem ?? let me know.

Comment: But Timer.periodic does not run in the background. Every time the app is closed, the timer will reset. And, that's a problem, because the code will be executed every 24 hours. What happens, if I restart the app minutes before 24 hours have passed, and the timer is reset?

Answer (score 0):

if I were you I would create a control table that lists all the affected Checkbox object, checked flag and last checked date. Reset the checked flag using stored procedure that runs every hour to see whether the 24 hour period has lapsed.
SQLite or plain CSV should suffice

Comment: I'd love if you could elaborate more on this approach.